# Django admin custom columns data format

Tags: django, django-admin

In my admin.ModelAdmin I have added a method to retrieve a description from another table:

```
   def get_nome_cli(self, obj):
       codice_cli = obj.cli_codice
       try:
           description= Cli.objects.filter(codice=codice_cli)
       except:
           nome='not found'       
       return '<a>{}></a>'.format(description)
```

It works but it displays the data like this:

```
<a>[<Cli: gigilatrottola - 2>]></a>
```

What am I missing to get it looking like this:

```
<a> gigilatrottola - 2 </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that only one `Cli` object can be filtered for every `codice_cli`, you might want to refactor your code to use the [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) queryset method. Secondly the `filter()` method does not raise an exception if the result is an empty list, so the try / except block is useless in that case.

```
def get_nome_cli(self, obj):
    codice_cli = obj.cli_codice
    try:
        description = Cli.objects.get(codice=codice_cli)
    except Cli.DoesNotExist:
        return 'Cli not found'       
    return '<a>{}></a>'.format(description)
get_nome_cli.allow_tags = True
```

You will have to set the `allow_tags` property to `True` if you would like to have clickable links in your fields.

Do not forget to add an [`__unicode__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#unicode), or a `__str__()` method to your model, depending on your flavour of python, that will offer the correct representation you are looking for.

```
class Cli(models.Model):
    # .....
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.description, self.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give field name instead of object directly.

like:
description.(field name)

suppose your field name is des then,

```
return '<a>%s - %s</a>', %(description.des, desctiprion.id)
```